# Extends en laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel

Buenos días tengo una duda sobre Laravel 5.5.
tengo mi blade

```
@extends('layouts.carreras.FacultadDeNegocios.AdministracionDeNegociosInternacionales')

@section('contenido')
<h1>Hola</h1>
@endsection
```

y quiero usarlo en:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">
<head>  <meta charset="UTF-8" /><title>DOCUMEsssNT</title></head>
<body>

@yield('contenido')
</body>
</html>
```

Pero cuando quiero ver el resultado no llama nada, ¿Estoy haciendo algo mal?

Comment: Seguro que en extends estás invocando al archivo?

Comment: sí, es la ruta donde esta mi archivo

Comment: Pero estás colocando el nombre del archivo o solo la carpeta?

Comment: estoy colando su ubicación y el nombre del archivo

Comment: creo que favorecería mucho a tu pregunta que coloques el arbol de archivos, es decir como estan organizadas tus carpetas

Comment: resources/views/layouts/carreras/FacultadDeNegocios/AdministracionDeNegociosInternacionales.blade.php

Así esta organizado amigo

Answer (score -1):

Comprueba que está bien la ubicación de tu template y que ambos archivos tengan terminación "`.blade.php`".